# Django Custom User and AuthenticationForm

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have found others' solutions helpful, but I still am having an issue.

Using a Custom User Model and also utilizing `AuthenticationForm` which said it support Custom User Models, I continuously receive this error: `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`

I also cannot utilize the `authentication` function as it always returns `None`.

---

My `settings.py` where inventory is my app name.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'inventory.User'
```

---

Here are my login portion in `views.py`

```
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.POST)
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('yay')

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        context['form'] = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'inventory/login.html', context)
```

---

Here is my `models.py`

```
class UserManager(AbstractUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, first_name, last_name, perm, password):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a first name')
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a last name')
        if not perm:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a position')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        if perm == 'e':
            user.employee = True
        elif perm == 'm':
            user.manager = True
        elif perm == 'o':
            user.owner = True

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', max_length=50, unique=True,)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='first name', max_length=50,)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='last name', max_length=50,)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    @property
    def is_employee(self):
        return self.employee

    @property
    def is_manager(self):
        return self.manager

    @property
    def is_owner(self):
        return self.owner

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    objects = UserManager()
```

---

Here is `login.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

---

I have searched for hours trying to figure out what my issue is, looking at `AuthenticationForm` documentation/code to see if it somehow searching to auth.User objects rather than my inventory.User objects, and it doesn't appear to be, especially after the documentation stated it would work with Custom User Models so long as you define `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check if the user is there in the database?

Comment: Yes I did Bill.

Comment: First you should add `objects = UserManager()` to your use model,Second you should extend PermissionsMixin for you user model like `from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin 
        class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):`

Comment: `objects = UserManager()` is actually at the bottom of the Model currently. Okay I will add in PermissionsMixin.

Comment: @Ykh Okay I added in the mixin, but I didn't do anything with it, still get the same error though, as expected.

Comment: So, `request.POST` sends the password as clear text, but the password stored in the database is hashed. I would assume `AuthenticationForm` is taking care of this by matching the clear text to the hash? Or is that the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You said at the top of you question:

> I also cannot utilize the `authentication` function as it always returns `None`.

Did you mean djangos [`authenticate` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) ? If that function returns `None`, then your `AuthenticationForm` will continue to fail the login.

Try something similar to this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
print(request.POST)
user = authenticate(**request.POST)  # pass all the keys to the function
if user is not None:
    print('A backend authenticated the credentials.')
    # Now you can try your Form again.
else:
    print('ERROR: no backend authenticated the credentials.')
    # Your Form will never login the user.
```

If this does not work, your `AuthenticationForm` won't probably work either.

Comment: Still doesn't work and I think I know why it doesn't work, but im not sure. If I have a custom model extending AbstractBaseUser, Authentication does not work probably because I need to define my own authentication backend when I use my own model (but idk why). If I just extend AbstractUser, I can utilize AuthenticationForm no problem. I might end up answering my own question.